# How to pass KnockoutJS model between scripts on same HTML page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I have a single HTML page on which I would like to use 2 separate scripts.

In my first script (let's call it `ScriptA`) I create a KnockoutJS model that is updated every second with an AJAX call and return it. This model is then mapped to UI elements using `data-bind` attributes.

Now since I want this page in two variants (first one where data is only displayed and second one where user can perform some actions) I don't want to include editing logic in `ScriptA`, so I created `ScriptB`. How can I now access model data? I tried by passing model variable to `ScriptB` on it's creation, but it holds no data.

Is there any easy way to solve this problem?

Comment: Impossible or too broad to answer without a repro of your scenario I'm afraid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like it would make more sense for scriptA to still house the editing logic and function calls (clicks, visible bindings etc) but also be able to determine whether those functions should be visible or active.

I would imagine that further down the road if you do manage to get two models bound to one page you're going to run into some unforeseen issues.

Comment: I found a way to use separate models for display and editing, so scriptA now only uses data from modelA and scriptB from modelB. I then bind modelA to div that is used for display and modelB to div that is used for editing. Because of that I don't need to store that extra data (used for editing) in my display model and instead of that I now make a separate AJAX call to get data used for editing when necessary. This eliminates unnecessary data traffic (you don't need data for editing unless you're actually editing right? ;)). Thank you for your help - D

Comment: That's tricky to get my head around, but it sounds pretty good!